# Can I use javax.persistence.OneToOne together with javax.persistence.ForeignKey?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

What is wrong with the following code? What I am trying to achieve is to nail down the name of the generated **foreign key**.

```
@Entity
public class Artifact {
@Id private long id;
@OneToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@ForeignKey(name="FK_ARTI_REPO")
private Repository repository;
```

But the the compilers  show this error message:

```
The annotation @ForeignKey is disallowed for this location.
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
@ForeignKey(name="FK_ARTI_REPO")
```

By

```
@JoinColumn(name = "COLUMN_NAME", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_ARTI_REPO"))
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown in any decent JPA docs, you don't use ForeignKey on its own, but instead in JoinColumn etc, so specify the @JoinColumn for the 1-1 relation

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/annotations.html#ForeignKey

Comment: Thanks very much, Neil. Indeed, I was able to use my goal by using the following code:
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FK_REPO_APPL"))
I find this less than intuitive, but: Who cares.